# How to count this in a faster way?

Tags: algorithms, combinations

It's a homework problem, it took me 20mins to do it,
and what's even worse is that I didn't get the correct exact answer....
(we are only asked to give an approximate number, I didn't lose any point tho...)

initially, a=0, b=0, C=0.
C is used to count the number of times of algorithm.

when a=0, b start from 0, 1, 2,... to whenever a^2+b^2 >= 2500, then stop
then a=1, b start from 0, 1, 2,... to whenever a^2+b^2 >= 2500, then stop
.
.
.
.
keep going on, and the last loop will be a=49, b=0,1,2,...9.

The question is the value of C.

I did it step by step, like when a=3, a^2=9,
then doing some "square" & "subtract" work knowing that b stops at b=49.

I'm wondering if there's a SMART way to do it fast and correctly without computers...

Thanks!!

Comment: This is the [Gauss circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss_circle_problem) There is no easy exact expression, though there are approximations.

Comment: @RossMillikan, Thanks for the heads up!!

Answer (score 0):

For any particular $a$, $b$ can go up to the largest integer below $\sqrt{2500-a^2}$. So for any particular $a$ we have the count equal to $\lfloor\sqrt{(2500-a^2)}\rfloor$. The half brackets mean the floor function. Then you would sum this up from $a=0$ up to $a=49$. (You could also sum to $a=50$, but the floor of 0 is 0.)

Plugging into wolframalpha I get 
$\sum_{a=0}^{a=49} \lfloor\sqrt{(2500-a^2)}\rfloor = 1961$

This is assuming that C is not incremented when $a^2+b^2 \ge 2500$. If C is incremented on the iteration on which this condition is satisfied, then we use the ceiling function instead to get $\sum_{a=0}^{a=49} \lceil\sqrt{(2500-a^2)}\rceil = 2006$

Comment: that's exactly how I did. but I'm thinking maybe there's another way to get C. otherwise, it really gonna take a long while to get to the answer.....

Comment: the answer is 2006 ><

Comment: Sorry, the factor of a should not be there. I took it out in an edit.

Comment: The answer is 2006 if you use the ceiling function. This means that when you hit the condition that a^2+b^2 >= 2500, then C is again incremented. I assumed from the problem statement that the a^2+b^2 >= 2500 condition was the loop control that determined if C would be incremented.

Comment: i see~~ thank u so much